# Transparent bitmap as background

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to make my background bitmap a little bit transparent so text could be a little bit more visible.

I am setting my background bitmap like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bitmap"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

This way text is not visible at all. How can I make my bitmap transparent? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `setAlpha()` for transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the layout file add set an ID to the root layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/background" android:background="...
```

And you can change the opacity of its background in the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout....);

    View backgroundView = findViewById(R.id.background);
    backgroundView.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
    ...
```